# UICollectionView in a UITableViewCell with Accessibility

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, accessibility

I'm adding Accessibility support to my iOS app and I'm having trouble with a collection view in one of my table view cells.

For example, when the user scrolls (horizontally) from the first cell to the second cell, Accessibility still reads the contents of the first cell. If I try to tap on a view in the second cell, it highlights an empty space to the left of the second cell (where the first cell would be but no longer visible) and reads the contents of the first cell.

When the collection view is *not* in a table view cell (i.e. a subview of a UIView), this does not happen.

I'm suspecting this has something to do with calling `UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification)` and I've tried calling it in many different places, but nothing has worked.

The following two screenshots show a collection view inside a UIView. Accessibility is enabled, so it gets selected with a black border when tapped.

1. When user taps first cell, it will get selected.

[image]

2. When the user taps 'Next', goes to the second cell, and taps the cell, the new cell will get selected.

[image]

The next two screenshots show the collection view inside a table view cell.

When the user taps the first cell, it gets selected and VoiceOver properly reads "I'm label 0".

[image]

However, when the user taps 'Next', goes to the next cell, and taps the second cell, it does not get selected and VoiceOver will still read, "I'm label 0".

[image]

The code is available [here on github](https://github.com/ykay/accessibility-collectionview).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had simillar problem which I eventually resolved.
I think that you have mismatched elements with

```
isAccessibilityElement = true
```

over each other.

I have a table view which scrolls vertically and each cell contains a title and collection view which scrolls horizontally.

I set `isAccessibilityElement` to `true` only on title and collection view cells, `false` on the rest.

Then, I subclassed `UICollectionView` and overrode the following `NSObject` methods:

```
func accessibilityElementCount() ->  Int
func accessibilityElement(at: Int) -> Any?
func index(ofAccessibilityElement element: Any) -> Int
```

It basically just tells the voice over that your collection view has these accessible elements. The collection view itself is not accessible which is not a problem, the contrary. You could probably use

```
open var accessibilityElements: [Any]?
```

instead.

Here is some more reading from documentation (UIAccessibility.h):

> `UIAccessibilityContainer` methods can be overridden to vend individual elements that are managed by a single `UIView`.
>
> For example, a single UIView might draw several items that (to an end user) have separate meaning and functionality.  It is important to vend each item as an individual accessibility element.
>
> Sub-elements of a container that are not represented by concrete `UIView`
>   instances (perhaps painted text or icons) can be represented using instances of `UIAccessibilityElement` class (see UIAccessibilityElement.h).
>
> Accessibility containers MUST return `NO` to -isAccessibilityElement.

To allow nice 3-finger voice over scroll you probably want to override

```
func accessibilityScroll(_ direction: UIAccessibilityScrollDirection) -> Bool
```

as well and scroll your collection view accordingly.

Comment: It would be great if you linked the source of your quote. (And inserting `>` at the beginning instead of four blanks will format it as quote instead of a code block.)

Comment: [Sample repository](https://github.com/akaDuality/RotorHeaders)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there was no need to subclass the UICollectionView.
Instead, define the accessibility elements in the container view (the UITableViewCell) as follows:

```
accessibilityElements = [titleLabel, collectionView]
```

Now all the collectionView elements can be navigated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
let nextCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(nextIndexPath)
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification,
                                argument: nextCell)
```

in your `onNextButtonTapped` method, after your call to `scrollToItemAtIndexPath`.

This will focus Accessibility on the next collection view cell.

Comment: I tried this and although it reads the new cell when it appears, tapping on the cell again will still cause the previous cell to be selected.

Comment: I believe pre-iOS 10, there is an issue with scroll views not automatically updating the `accessibilityFrame`. I'm not sure of the details, but you may want to look into it. Your screenshots show that the frame is still focused on the first cell. Is that the case with the modified code?

Comment: When UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification is posted, it will select the second cell correctly (and VoiceOver will read out "I'm label 1"), however further interactions will always select the first cell again.

Comment: Did you eventually end up solving this? @marcelli407

Comment: No I haven't @ShaiMishali